# How can I make VS2013 use windows sdk 7.0A?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

VS2013 uses sdk from the windos_kit 8.1 as default.
How could I make it to use the old sdk like windows sdk 7.0A?

Comment: It has built-in support to use SDK 7.1, seems a bit pointless to force it to target 7.0A.  Change the Platform Toolset setting to "v120_xp".

Comment: Hi, by changing the platform toolset, will it affect the compiler being used?

Comment: No, just the SDK declarations.